# Problem with Quaternions and Unity's Euler Angle Convention

Tags: c#, unity, rotation, quaternion

So I want to rotate an UI-Element according to my magneticHeading, I just want to apply the magnetic heading to the z rotation in EulerAngles. So I tried to do so, which brought me to some weird rotations, then I tried this :

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.z, transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y);`

Which also lead to some weird rotation, but I don't understand why, since in my understanding this should actually do nothing to the rotation...

This:

`transform.rotation = transform.rotation;`

is working again, like I expected it and does nothing to the rotation.

Can someone explain me why the `Quaternion.Euler` stuff is not working and how I can fix my problem?

Solution :

```
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, -temp.z);
    transform.Rotate(0,0,Input.compass.magneticHeading);
    temp = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
```

So I'm reseting the `Rotation` first and then set the z value to the `magneticHeading`, the reset with `Quaternion.identity` did not work for me, so I just subtracted the last value.

Comment: Look-up "Euler angles" and "Euler angle conventions". I believe unity is using the ZYX one, but you need to make sure this is the case.

Comment: the order of my values should be correct and even if not I tried all the possible combinations :D

Answer (score 1):

Converting between a Quaternion (`transform.rotation`) and an Euler angle triplet is not possible the way you wrote it.

See the API http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html for the meaning of the `transform.rotation` property.

If you want to double check or verify that your Euler angles are correct, you can convert them to a quaternion and then set them. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles.

Comment: For completeness you could add the solution to your answer which is 'transform.Rotate', which takes the triplet by itself... thanks a lot for bringing me on the right track :)

Comment: Well I thought about it and I got an input like 150, which is the degree, which the map should be rotated at. But transform.Rotate will rotate the map by additional 150 degrees with each update (I sat there laughing about how that looked...). But how can I fix that without storing the last value and calculating the difference?

Comment: What about resetting the transform each time: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Identity;` and then using `transform.Rotate(..)`? I haven't tried it (cannot do that at the moment anyway), but it should do what you need to.

Comment: Okay, exactly this did not work, but I got it working now and will update the question with the working code thanks :)